# Use Docker to run a build process

Tags: docker, build-process, docker-compose

I'm using `docker` and `docker-compose` to set up a build pipeline. I've got a front-end that's written in javascript and needs to be built before being used. The backend is written in `go`.

To make this component integrate with the rest of our `docker-compose` setup, I want to do the building in a docker image as well.

This is the flow I'm going for:

- during build do:

  - build the frontend stuff and put it in `/output` (that is bound to the
    `output` volume
  - build the backend server
- when running do:

  - run the server, it has access to the build files in `/output`

I'm quite new to `docker` and `docker-compose` so I'm not sure if this is possible, or even the right thing to do.

For reference, here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  output:
    driver: local

services:
  frontend:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - output:/output
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    depends_on:
      - frontend
    volumes:
      - output:/output
```

and `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node

# create working dir
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD package.json /usr/src/app/package.json

# install packages
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app

# build frontend files and place results in /output 
RUN npm build
RUN cp /usr/src/app/build/* /output
```

And `backend/Dockerfile`:

```
 FROM go

 # copy and build server
 COPY . /usr/src/backend
 WORKDIR /usr/src/backend
 RUN go build

 # run the server
 ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/backend/main"]
```

Something is wrong here, but I do not know what. It seems as though the output of the build step are not persisted in the `output` volume.  What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot attach a volume during `docker build`.
The reason for this is that the goal of the `docker build` command is to build an image, and nothing else, it doesn't need to have volumes, as Dockerfile has ADD / COPY.

To produce your output, you should create a script which mostly does the `npm install ; npm build ; cp /usr/src/app/build/* /output` from your current dockerfile and use this script as the entrypoint / cmd in your dockerfile.

I'm not sure compose can run this, but in any case, I find it more clear wrapped in a shell script that first executes the frontend builder container, then executing the backend container with the output directory as a volume.